# Sentence caps for the flags in your flag history

Tags: feature-request, design, flags, flag-history, capitalization

On [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com), your flag history shows flags you've raised with proper capitalization:

[image]

Whereas on all other sites, like on Meta, the flags aren't capitalized:

[image]

That makes it inconsistent, and I actually quite like the caps flags, at least in the flag history.  It also looks better with plain-text flags like NAA ones:

[image]

Could we have flag-capitalization elsewhere on the network too?

Comment: At least, when they aren't causing other problems like multiple lines of links/text...